# MVC3 not finding resources

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to start a mvc3 website. But when I load the server I get this error.

> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.

My routes file looks like this

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
               "Default",                                              // Route name
               "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
               new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
           );
            routes.MapRoute(
               "States",                                              // Route name
               "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
               new { controller = "States", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
           );
        }
```

Comment: I'd suggest reading [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx),  you don't seem to understand routes. But that might not be your only problem. I'd suggest putting an html in the folder to see if you've got IIS set up to correctly point to it first.

Comment: I'm not using ISS, i'm using vs's builtin dev server

Comment: In that case it is possibly your routes. Can you paste your Controller code, and the url you are trying to request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noted that you have two possibly conflicting route registrations. Try removing the first registration and leaving only this one:

```
           routes.MapRoute(
               "States",
               "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               new { controller = "States", action = "Index", id = "" }
           );
```